# AWS API-gateway manual deploy required?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

The API tends to go down when I re-deploy a REST-API using AWS API-gateway and cloudformation (*AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi*). Then a manual "deploy of the API" through AWS-console is required to fix it. This creates downtime until I have done this. Which options do I have to prevent this?

Ref: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-deploy-api.html

Answer (score 0):

In your CloudFormation template, be sure to include a `AWS:ApiGateway:Deployment` resource to trigger the actual deployment after a change.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-deployment.html

APIs are deployed without downtime. While the new configuration is propagated API Gateway responds to requests using the previous config. Once the new configuration is available and a new request comes in it will be handled using the updated configuration.

Comment: I have this actually. I should probably update my question with my cloudformation template.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423439/cloudformation-doesnt-deploy-to-api-gateway-stages-on-update) for why it's not as simple as this answer suggests.