# How to automate API Gateway deployment via SAM deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

When I changed `AWS::ApiGateway::Method` properties by `AWS SAM` template and deployed it. but I noticed that change was not reflected until I deploy API manually from AWS management console. I think it is because I didn't change the resource of `AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment` and `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage` on the template.(The deployment history of `AWS::ApiGateway::Stage` was not updated.)

How can I reflect the change when I trigger sam deploy?

Comment: Related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41423439/cloudformation-doesnt-deploy-to-api-gateway-stages-on-update
As suggested in one of the answers there, a possible workaround is to (manually or automatically) run `aws apigateway create-deployment` after `sam deploy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to manually deploy the api from the console :) it's a limitation at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and noted.

Comment: I have not tried this approach, looks like if you change the logical name of  the deployment resource, it will trigger the deployment it seems, have a crack at it if you want, https://medium.com/@ngchiwang/aws-apigateway-deployment-not-update-3e04fcffe85b

Comment: Thanks. I understand the approach to always recreate the stage resource by putting timestamp. wow. I'll try it.

Comment: but I noticed I always need to put timestamp when I modify the setting related to API gateway. have to remember to change...

Comment: Ya it's not the best solution

Comment: @d.y Actually what I did is to create another task after sam-deploy which deploys my API base on a domain name. if it's still relevant I can post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you are still looking for a solution for this, SAM has recently(March 2023) introduced a property under `AWS::Serverless::Api` called `AlwaysDeploy` which forces API to be deployed even when there is no changes to API whenever there is sam deploy.

Reference:

1. [`AWS::Serverless::Api` Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-alwaysdeploy)
2. [PR to SAM on Github](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/pull/2935)

Note that this will only work if you have your sam cli up to date (>v1.78.0) in your local machine or CI/CD where you will be running `sam build`.